# How do I determine the underlying WCF exception in my client application?

Tags: c#, wcf

When testing my application using the WCF test client. When I try to retrieve a lot of data from my service in one go. I get the usual message about exceeding the size quota:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

However, when testing this in my client application. I get a different error with no indication of the problem. The exception thrown is a `CommunicationException`.

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

There is also no inner exception indicating that the maximum size was exceeded.

Is there any way to accurately determine that the exception was caused by trying to return too much data at once or will I have to settle for a generic error message?

Comment: I have got the same issue. lol